# Section 0 in Ernest B. Vinberg, "Linear Representations of groups" Q.7(e)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I know from the answers at the back of the book that the following map:

$$(S(t)f)(x) = e^tf (x + t),$$  where $S: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S(V)$ and $V$ is the subspace of all polynomials with real coefficients and $t \in \mathbb{R}, f \in V.$

Is a linear representation (but I do not know how?). Even though I found that $S(t)$ is linear when I put instead of $f$, $\alpha f + \beta f$.  I know that for the given map $S$ to be a linear representation it must be a homomorphism, but I see that it is not a homomorphism because $f(x + t +t^`) \neq f(x +t^`) + f(t)$ ?

Could anyone clarify this discrepancy for me please?

**EDIT:**
$(S(t + t^`)f)(x) = e^(t +t`) f (x + t + t`) = e^t e^t` f(x + t + t`)$, then what shall I do next?

Comment: What is $R{{}}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown the reals

Comment: So $R$ is the same as what you've called $\Bbb R$ later on. Now, what is $S(V)$?

Comment: yes. $S(V)$ I do not know .... may be the space of all invertible linear operators @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Anyway, I expect the equation you need to verify is $$S(t')(S(t)f)=S(t+t')f,$$ not the one you state.

Comment: I have corrected the reals @LordSharktheUnknown thank you

Comment: yes this is the equation I need to verify ..... but while verifying it I need the one I stated above in the question @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: I doubt it; perhaps you could share the workings that led you to that conclusion.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  I am adding it now

Comment: The next thing to do is compute $S(t')(S(t)f)$.

Comment: It worked @LordSharktheUnknown :) thank you